# How can I read data from other sectors in the ACR122U Mifare?

Tags: python, mifare, pyscard

I have this simple code to read my ACR122U Mifare card:

```py
def read_card():
    apdu = [0xFF, 0xCA, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]
    cardtype = AnyCardType()
    try:
        cardrequest = CardRequest(timeout=60, cardType=cardtype)
        cardservice = cardrequest.waitforcard()
    except CardRequestTimeoutException:
        return None
    observer = ConsoleCardConnectionObserver()
    cardservice.connection.addObserver(observer)
    cardservice.connection.connect()
    response, sw1, sw2 = cardservice.connection.transmit(apdu)
    cardservice.connection.disconnect()
```

The code works and I can read the card data. I want to read other sectors/blocks, for example sector 15.

I try to change the apdu values but without success.

Is it possible to read other sectors? I haven't found any examples in the official pyscard doc.